# Git error: fatal: unable to connect a socket (Invalid argument)

Tags: windows, git, proxy, msysgit

I've got msysGit (Git on Windows) working just fine on my home machine, but at work, where we are behind a Microsoft ISA proxy, I get the following error when I do a Git clone:

```
H:
cd \
git clone git://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles.git
```

Output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in H:/vimfiles/.git/
github.com[0: 65.74.177.129]: errno=Invalid argument
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Invalid argument)
```

I've tried setting the *http_proxy* environment variable to:

```
http://our-proxy-server:8088
```

I've set the Git *http.proxy* configuration directive:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://our-proxy-server:8088
```

Neither of the above makes a difference.

Doing a Git clone with `http://` instead of `git://` yields this:

```
H:
cd \
git clone http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles.git
```

Output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in H:/vimfiles/.git/
fatal: http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles.git/info/refs download error - The    requested URL returned error: 407
```

407 is of course an authentication error.

Is there a way to get Git working from behind a proxy, specifically an ISA proxy? I don't know if it's going to be worth pursing this.

Comment: just added another potential fix

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I take it you have now a Git1.6.4?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I had the exact same error; but the [`~/.gitconfig` global config file](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) was the key.

If you have a proxy with authentication you need to put in it:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://login:password@our-proxy-server:8088
```

And it just works (with '`git clone http:`')

Example of a blog detailing the same setup: [GIT clone over HTTP: who knew?](http://rip747.wordpress.com/2008/09/12/git-clone-over-http-who-knew/)

---

If it still fails in 407, it could be related to a problem with [git-fetch losing authentication tokens on the second HTTP GET](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/1/3/234850/thread). A [more recent version of libcurl](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2008/12/08/scp-and-sftp-with-libcurl-on-windows/) might be needed.

---

Update January 2011: [jbustamovej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567525/jbustamovej) mentions in [his answer (upvoted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496277/git-error-fatal-unable-to-connect-a-socket-invalid-argument/4630559#4630559) his blog post "[GitHub Behind Corporate Proxy](http://jmjpro.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/github-behind-corporate-proxy/)", which adds this:

> It’s important to note that **if your login has a backslash**, as in `domain\login`, **you must escape the backslash**, as in:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://domain\\\login:password@our-proxy-server:8088
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't get this working. It still gives me a 407 (authentication) error even though I've set the proxy (complete with username and password) in both the environment and .gitconfig.

Comment: I just tried this again, since msysGit has been updated, and it worked. Hurrah! I guess libcurl must have been updated in the latest version.

Comment: Charles, what version do you have? With the new version, where do you put the proxy configuration? I'm getting the same problem and I tried a lot of manners.

Answer (score 19):

Even after configuring the proxy, you might be unable to connect, since the proxy is disallowing Git protocol traffic. In this case, you might want to try using "http" instead of "git"

> H:>git clone
> http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles.git

Also, if you are using an automated proxy config file (.pac), just open it in a text editor. It is quite a easy to following scripting language, with a bunch of conditions to redirect to the most efficient proxy. Find the one that allows general purpose traffic (typically, the last configured proxy), and configure it as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: Great! i had a similar problem with git, it was giving this error "Unable to connect to socket (no error)". I configured my --global http.proxy and i used http instead of git when cloning, and it worked.

Comment: This is exactly what my issue was. I didn't have to bother with the proxy stuff.

Comment: Obviously, this only works for git repos that are hosted via http. Ie. it'll work for github.com based repos. For others, you will need to get git working via your firewall/proxy

Answer (score 3):

Do you have [SOCKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) proxy? If you have, you could try **FreeCap** to socksify your Git connection. I've been using Git this way for a while.

If not, still try FreeCap. IIRC it might be able to use HTTP proxies, but I haven't tried that.

I usually socksify **cmd.exe** using FreeCap, and from then on (almost) all cmdline programs that I start from that session are socksified too. That's why I recommended Free Cap, since SocksCap (another alternative) doesn't work that way.

As for using *http.proxy*, it for some reason never worked for me with the MinGW version and my company's HTTP proxies.

Comment: Thanks for this, FreeCap looks interesting. Are you able to elaborate on how you're using Git with it?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working via a very convoluted route. Here's how:

1. I have OpenSSH running on my home machine (a Vista box) [running under Cygwin](http://www.petri.co.il/setup-ssh-server-vista.htm)
2. I am using Bitvise Tunnelier's [Dynamic tunneling via integrated SOCKS/HTTP CONNECT proxy](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier.html#port-forwarding).
3. I then use [Freecap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng/) (thanks Marko) to "SOCKify" GIT-GUI. Unfortunately, you have to setup each .exe individually and run them from within Freecap, so you can't univerally SOCKify all of the git command line tools. You can setup explicit command-line commands within Freecap, but you have to setup each individually, which kind of defeats the purpose. This is why I've just setup GIT-GUI in this crazy elaborate system

Amazingly, it seems to work, although I've not tested everything yet. It'll clone, certainly, which is a start.

If anyone has a better solution, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 and [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) worked for me after getting 407 errors and other junk from GitHub.

File *.gitconfig*:

```
[http]
      proxy = http://127.0.0.1:5865
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://login:password@PROXY_SERVER:PORT
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28308242/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows 7:

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.git
```

Output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Users/Jay/temp/php-sdk/.git/
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)
```

I finally realized it was [AVG AntiVirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVG_AntiVirus) software running. I disabled the "resident shield" within AVG, and it worked like a charm.

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/php-sdk.git
```

Output:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Users/Jay/temp2/php-sdk/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 223, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (179/179), done.
emote: Total 223 (delta 84), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (223/223), 37.32 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (84/84), done.
```