# downloading lexandera/Aardwolf.git using git bash (Windows); fatal error - unable to connec to github.com

Tags: android, windows, git, mobile, github

This is somewhat unrelated to my question, but I found this great JavaScript debugger for mobile development, one that allows breakpoints, not some trivial console debugger that is commonplace in this environment.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/lexandera/Aardwolf) and it also contains setup instructions, as well, which is where I'm having problems.

FYI, I am running Windows XP SP2.

I downloaded node.js and git version 1.7.7.1-preview20111027 and installed them both.  With git, I chose the recommended settings for Windows, installing the bash in its own environment, not mixing at all with Windows command line!

I started the git bash and typed exactly as it's printed on the link's setup instructions.  I pasted what was displayed in the git bash below:

```
git clone git://github.com/lexandera/Aardwolf.git
Cloning into Aardwolf...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Invalid argument
```

It creates the Aardwolf directory but there is no content inside.

I would appreciate some help, here.  I'm a bit lost on how to resolve this.

Thank you.

**Update**

I took at this link for help: [Git error: fatal: unable to connect a socket (Invalid argument)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496277/git-error-fatal-unable-to-connect-a-socket-invalid-argument) and I tried modifying the command from git:// to https:// a few times.  I closed the bash window and opened up a couple of times and the https:// modification miraculously worked.

I'll accept that maybe the https location was down or busy and that's why it worked now.  But I don't understand why the git:// is not working.  What is the reason?

Thank you.

**Update 2**

Ostensibly, it likely a proxy issue.  A google search reveals that the default TCP port for git protocol is 9418, at least for *nix platforms.  Is this also true for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you're behind a corporate proxy, `git://` is very unlikely to work. I've had similar issues than yours with `https://` protocol.

As it looks like you're only willing to clone a remote repository, and not push to it later, switching to plain `http://` should solve your issue.

```
$ git clone http://github.com/lexandera/Aardwolf.git
Cloning into 'Aardwolf'...
remote: Counting objects: 494, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (250/250), done.
remote: Total 494 (delta 237), reused 470 (delta 213)
Receiving objects: 100% (494/494), 79.99 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (237/237), done.
```

Answer (score 0):

Git provides a way to rewrite URLs using git config. Simply issue the following command:

git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
Now, as if by magic, all git commands will perform a substitution of git:// to https://