# fatal: unable to access : Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a problem with my git, when I pull or push to repository of bitbucket. I always get this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/****/**':
>   Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection timed out

I tried all solution but it can not resolved.

Comment: Did you try opening bitbucket in browser ?

Comment: Did you add bitbucket.org to your /etc/hosts file? If so, take it out.

Comment: @JimRedmond I tried that. Worked for the first time . Now the issue showed again

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Yes. I can open open it in browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading git if you have the old version.

Check your git version:

```
$ git --version
```

Run the following to upgrade:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE: 28-08-2020**

This is **Temp** fix but at least working for me after bitbucket new IP changed

Note:- `hosts` file can be found in windows at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and in Linux it exists at `/etc/hosts`. make sure you edit with admin rights i.e in windows open notepad as administrator and then open host file. In Linux `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` from the terminal from any location :)

just add the below line in hosts file

`18.205.93.0    bitbucket.org`

For all existing users who previously edited `etc/hosts` file and now stopped working just replace the old IP address of bitbucket with new one i.e in `etc/hosts`

REPLACE
`104.192.143.3(old IP whatever)     bitbucket.org`

with

`18.205.93.0    bitbucket.org`

Happy Coding!

Comment: Interestingly enough in 2021, Bitbucket started having issues for me recently, on the 104.x number that the nslookup (via even the internet sites) I can't get connected to.  But the 18.205 number still works.    So thank you, as having a working route/ip makes my life a lot simpler...

Comment: What if repo is hosted on azure dep ops

Answer (score 6):

**Recommendation 1:**  Just you need to remove your origin and set the origin again, then try to pull/push. Hopefully, it will work for you.

```
 git remote -v
 git remote remove origin    
 git remote add origin https://habibbd@bitbucket.org/softwarebd/mida-oss.git
```

**Recommendation 2:**   Remove those of lines from `Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` file if anyone of these lines is available.

```
 104.192.143.1 bitbucket.org
 104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
 18.205.93.0 bitbucket.org
```

**Recommendation 3:** Change your network connection/provider. Sometimes your network provider causes this kind of issue.

**Recommendation 4:**  Check firewall settings. Sometimes it was the issue for showing this kind of message.

Comment: It works, really a best answer.

Comment: What if repo is hosted on azure dep ops?

Comment: Recommendation 3 worked for me

Comment: Recommendation 1 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Check if you require VPN and reconnect. That was the reason for me. After I reconnected to the VPN everything worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In .git directory update file called config, remove this link. Post this do 'git pull', it'll ask for your credentials again & pull will successfully go through

[image: reference to localhost]

Answer (score -2):

First, you are not pushing to [GitHub](https://github.com/), but [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product).

Second, since [BitBucket status](https://status.bitbucket.org/) seems OK, there must be a network or **[proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496504/6309)** or firewall issue on your side.

Regarding the proxy specifically:

- check your `~/gitconfig` file content
- remove any proxy line
- set a proxy in your environment variables:

  ```
  export http_proxy=http://someuser:somepassword@192.168.1.1:80
  ```

Comment: "I  tried all solution but it can not resolved.": what solution did you tried? What is your OS and Git version?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20705349)

Comment: @Dev911 Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.